# Definite Integral as a Sum of Limit

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, summation

Evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \right)^{1/x}$$

For my approach I took the limit to be A and then took log on both sides as a result of which the Summation comes inside the log. I am not able to solve further. 
What approach do we take after this.

Comment: was that the right place for the index? The image had it in a different place.

Comment: Please Check the edited post.

Comment: images are discouraged and mathjax is encouraged. If you click on the 'edited <some time> ago' link, you can see the previous mathjax form and choose one of them. I had put in the right conversion a while ago and it has been changed.